# White space between pagination in WP-filebase

Tags: css, wordpress, pagination

I try to style WP-filebase pagination in a page. I have used WP-pagenavi in blog articles and I got it to look as I wanted: The numbers are in boxes side by side.

As I haven't found the way to use WP-pagenavi with WP-filebase (I also read that it doesn't work with pages in WP) I have tried to style the pagination in WP-filebase to look the same, but I only get the numbers in boxes side by side BUT white space between them.

I tried to use margin-left to get rid of the white space, but then I got other problems. The border while hovering is not showing on the right. It seems that the boxes are overlapping each other on the right-side. How to fix this with css?

My css looks like this:

```
    .tablenav-pages {
        clear: both;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-family: 'Gotham A','Gotham B', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        padding: 6px 14px;
        font-size: 15px;
    /*  margin-left: 6px;*/
    }
    .tablenav-pages a, .tablenav-pages span {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #a30083;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 6px 14px;
    /*  margin-left: -6px;*/
    }
    .tablenav-pages a:hover {
        border-color: #a30083;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 6px 14px;
    }
    .tablenav-pages span.current {
        background-color: #a30083;
        border-color: #a30083;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 6px 14px;
     }
    div.tablenav-pages {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: It may be helpful if you also send the HTML for the pagination, or even better the webpage with the pagination.

Comment: `code`<div class="tablenav-pages"><a class="prev page-numbers" href="../tutkimusjulkaisut/tyopapereita/?wpfb_list_page=2">&laquo; Edellinen</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href='../tutkimusjulkaisut/tyopapereita/?wpfb_list_page=1'>1</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href='../tutkimusjulkaisut/tyopapereita/?wpfb_list_page=2'>2</a>
<span class='page-numbers current'>3</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href='../tutkimusjulkaisut/tyopapereita/?wpfb_list_page=4'>4</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="../tutkimusjulkaisut/tyopapereita/?wpfb_list_page=4">Seuraava &raquo;</a></div>

Answer (score 1):

Aila, you have spaces between your elements.

Ex:

```
<a class="prev page-numbers" href="../tutkimusjulkaisut/tyopapereita/?wpfb_list_page=2">&laquo; Edellinen</a> <a class='page-numbers' href='../tutkimusjulkaisut/tyopapereita/?wpfb_list_page=1'>1</a>
```

After removing the spaces, they are now flush together:
http://jsfiddle.net/yfp37mac/

Comment: You are right :-) I only have a problem to find the place to remove the spaces. It's a plugin WP-filebase, which is doing the code. I took the code from browser.